# How to make the size of Angular Corner Ribbon Component dynamic?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

I have referred to a pure CSS implementation of a corner ribbon and created an Angular component from it.

Reference:

https://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/oLdoWb       (original),

https://codepen.io/apappas1129/pen/OJBzmrV  (SCCS re-write)

The issue I am having trouble is when I want to make the ribbon size dynamic by exposing an `@Input size` in `px` for example. I was thinking of utilizing the `transform scale` function of CSS but scaling also needs updating of the positions with `translateY` and `translateX` so that the ribbon sits perfectly at the corner of its parent element. But It's hard to wrap my head around the math for it. Perhaps there is another way.

Below is the implementation so far:

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, Output, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'ribbon',
  template: `
  <div class="ribbon ribbon-{{position}}"
       [style.cursor]="isClickable ? 'pointer' : 'default'"
       (click)="this.click.emit()">
    <div class="ribbon-label"><span>{{ label }}</span></div>
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['ribbon.component.scss']
})
export class RibbonComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() position: 'top-left' | 'top-right' | 'bottom-right' | 'bottom-left' = 'top-left';
  /** Default value is a No-Break Space so as to not break the ribbon shape when no label is set. */
  @Input() label = '\u00A0';
  /** Can be set to one of the scss color variables defined from the theme.scss
   * or a custom CSS color value such as `rgba` , HEX, HSL, or a CSS predefined color name. */
  @Input() color: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'warning' | 'danger' | string = 'danger';
  @Output() click = new EventEmitter<void>();

  
  get isClickable(): boolean {
    return !!this.click.observers.length;
  }

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Force parent/container element to have position relative
    // so that the ribbon's offset using position absolute is secured
    const parent = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
    this.renderer.setStyle(parent, 'position', 'relative');
  }
}
```

```scss
$primary-color: #3498db; // base color of the ribbon
$secondary-color: darken($primary-color, 10%); // darkened base color for the folded part
$label-color: #fff;

// TODO: Make side of the square dynamic. This can be done by bidnign transform scale but offset calculation will be tricky
$main-width: 150px; // ribbon is wrapped by a square
$ribbon-width: $main-width * 1.5; // 225px
$ribbon-underside-length: $main-width * 0.033; // ~5px, How much of the underside of the folded ribbon is exposed.
$ribbon-padding: $main-width * 0.1; // ~15px
$label-min-height: $main-width *0.12; // ~18px
$offset: $ribbon-underside-length * -2; // ~-10px

.ribbon {
  width: $main-width;
  height: $main-width;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: $ribbon-underside-length solid $secondary-color;
  }

  .ribbon-label {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: $ribbon-width;
    padding: $ribbon-padding 0;
    background-color: $primary-color;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: $label-color;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: $label-min-height !important; // lock in so the ribbon's thickness is unaffected by the label's font-size
  }
}

@mixin ribbon-position($positionY, $positionX, $angle) {
  .ribbon-#{$positionY}-#{$positionX} {
    #{$positionY}: $offset; // top or bottom
    #{$positionX}: $offset; // left or right

    // #region folded sides of the ribbon
    &::before,
    &::after {
      border-#{$positionY}-color: transparent;
      border-#{$positionX}-color: transparent;
    }

    &::before {
      #{$positionY}: 0; // top or bottom
      #{if($positionX == 'left', 'right', 'left')}: 0; // anchor on the opposite side
    }

    &::after {
      #{if($positionY == 'top', 'bottom', 'top')}: 0; // anchor on the opposite side
      #{$positionX}: 0; // left or right
    }
    // #endregion

    .ribbon-label {
      #{if($positionX == 'left', 'right', 'left')}: -25px; // offset on opposite side
      #{$positionY}: 30px; // top or bottom
      transform: rotate(#{$angle}deg);

      // Corrective centering of label for top-right and bottom-left ribbon
      @if ($positionY == 'top' and $positionX == 'right' ) or ($positionY == 'bottom' and $positionX == 'left') {
        span {
          padding-left: 1.5ch; // add padding equivalent to 150% width of "0" in current font-size
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include ribbon-position(top, left, -45);
@include ribbon-position(top, right, 45);
@include ribbon-position(bottom, left, 225);
@include ribbon-position(bottom, right, -225);
```

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to somehow make this silly `calc` values that are used for `transform-origin` to know where to anchor the ribbon before `transform` scaling.
Here is an example of [scaled-up](https://codepen.io/apappas1129/pen/NWOXMye?editors=1000) ribbons and [scaled-down](https://codepen.io/apappas1129/pen/oNapEKV?editors=1000) ribbons.

The `5px` can be replaced with a variable that I would call `undersideWidth` (The width of the exposed underside of the folded ribbon). Then the value used in `transform: scale()` can be cointained in a variable named `amount` (Which should be 0 to 1). At this point it's only a matter of simplicification of this dumb `calc` formula I made.

So to summarize I managed to somehow make it dynamic with the following:

top-left:

```
transform: scale(amount);
transform-origin: calc(0% + (((1 - amount) * undersideWidth)) + (1 + amount) * undersideWidth) calc((0% + ((1 - amount) * undersideWidth)) + (1 + amount) * undersideWidth);
```

top-right:

```
transform: scale(amount);
transform-origin: calc((100% - ((1 - amount) * undersideWidth)) + (1 + amount) * undersideWidth* -1) calc((0% + ((1 - amount) * undersideWidth)) + (1 + amount) * undersideWidth);
```

bottom-left:

```
transform: scale(amount);
transform-origin: calc((0% + ((1 - amount) * undersideWidth)) + (1 + amount) * undersideWidth) calc(((100% - ((1 - 0.5) * undersideWidth)) - ((1 - amount) * undersideWidth)) + (1 + amount) * undersideWidth* -1);
```

bottom-right:

```
transform: scale(amount);
transform-origin: calc((100% - ((1 - amount) * undersideWidth)) + (1 + amount) * undersideWidth* -1) calc((100% - ((1 - amount) * undersideWidth)) + (1 + amount) * undersideWidth* -1);
```

I'm pretty sure the the formulas can be broken down into conditions based on position. i.e. top vs bottom and left vs right.

The easiest observable value between the 4 different positions is the reference point for where to offset from. If the Y position is `top-*`, the reference point for `transform-origin Y` is `0%`., If it's `bottom-*`, it will be `100%`. Likewise for the `transform-origin X`, it will be `0%` for `*-left` and `100%` for `*-right`.

The rest of the formula are based on the scaled width of the exposed underside of the folded ribbon to decide how much to offset and in what direction (condition for when the offset is negative or positive).

I need help in simplifying this into functions that return the correct `transform-origin X` and `Y` values for each of the four positions.

Comment: See if you can figure [this one](https://renevanderlende.one/discord-stuff/custom-vars-ribbon-new.html) out. It has been a while since I worked on it: responsive, nested, resizable and animatable ribbons. CSS only. Source is commentend...

Comment: Thanks for this @RenevanderLende! I'll see what I can do. I'm trying my hardest not to make my nose bleed from reading all this alien math magic. I also am looking at the credited/referenced links you provided like [stereokai's gist](https://gist.github.com/stereokai/7666bfe93929b14c2dced148c79e0e97) and mathisfunforum. :) I don't think I can comprehend any of these. haha.

And since my ribbon angle is fixed at 45 degrees, I'm considering to overhaul this and base my component on your [ers-ribbon-commented](https://github.com/renevanderlende/ers-ribbon/blob/main/ers-ribbon-comments.html)

Comment: Cool, let me know how that works out for you. It's a bit simpler than the example I gave before, but should work fine.

Comment: I know sizing is in there, check out the large green ribbon (6). The *1/1 Linear Equation in CSS* stuff may be a bit cryptic, but scaling can be done out of the box. The LEQ math simply uses a minimum size (`--y1h` and `--y1w`) at `--x1` small viewport size and a maximum size (`--y2h` and `--y2w`) at `--x2` large viewport size and calculates the ribbon size relative to the current `100vmin` (`--x`). You can set those (x,y) values per ribbon. Just made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/VwEyQLx) you can tinker with. CSS line 149+ sets defaults, line 314+ set values per ribbon.

Comment: Thank you for making the Codepen. I hope I can do it... This is is trickier than I thought, as I have to port some values from TS through angular [style.*]` binding. This would then require some... I'm already lost at the thought of how I can bind from a single value and propagate the calculated ones to css. haha.

Comment: Perhaps this post is asking for too much and actually demands for an overhaul rather than a simple "add-on" code.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and dig into the math of *linear equation* **y=mx+b** in general. It will make your responsive design life so much easier: `.some-class { size-property: calc(m * x + b) }` does one calculation where you would otherwise need a list of media queries. E.g. I always use `body { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }` as base font size. 14px on a 320px vmin and 20px on a 1280px vmin. This is *y=mx+b* with (320,14) and (1280,20).

Comment: @RenevanderLende, Is there any chance that the linear equation you shared is relevant to these values I have generated in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/apappas1129/pen/oNapEKV)? See the `transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-65px) translateY(-65px);`. I am not sure if we can make something out of this.

Comment: Simply determine how wide the ribbon has to be on a mobile and on a desktop and post these values in your codepen somewhere. I'll have a look later today (in 2-3 hrs) and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to utilize `transform-origin` to staple the ribbon on the given corner. I am not sure with why I need to add `2 * u` here to the anchor point.

```html
  [style.transform]="transform"
  [style.transformOrigin]="transformOrigin"
```

```js
  /** Applies `transform: scale(amount)` */
  @Input() scale?: number;

  get transform(): string | null {
    return this.scale ? `scale(${this.scale})` : null;
  }

  get transformOrigin(): string | null {
    if (!this.scale) return null;
    const u = '5px'; // length of the ribbon's exposed underside.
    const anchorX = this.position.includes('left') ? '0%' : '100%';
    const anchorY = this.position.includes('top') ? '0%' : '100%';
    const X = `calc(${anchorX} ${this.position.includes('left') ? '+' : '-'} 2 * ${u})`;
    const Y = `calc(${anchorY} ${this.position.includes('top') ? '+' : '-'} 2 * ${u})`;
    return `${X} ${Y}`;
  }
```